# Brightway2 modification of an existing ecoinvent activity

Tags: brightway

There was a previous issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033781/create-a-new-activity-in-brightway2-based-on-an-existing-ecoinvent-activity?rq=1) but it didn't help me with my problem:

When I try to change an exchanged amount with .amount = myamount
I always get a "can't set attribute error".

Here is what i did:

```
## search for activity
msw = [get_activity(key) for key, ds in eco.items() if 
           'treatment of municipal solid waste, incineration' in ds['name'] and 
           ds['location'] == ('BE') and ds['unit'] == 'kilogram']
```

and

```
##make a copy
msw_be = msw.copy()

##get exchange
Carbon_dioxide_non_fossil = [exc for exc in mswi_be.biosphere() if 'Carbon dioxide, non-fossil' in exc['name']][0]
```

and then

```
##change amount
Carbon_dioxide_non_fossil.amount = 0.75152
```

here is where i get the error.
Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You activities act like dictionaries, and don't support attribute access. Try this instead:

```
Carbon_dioxide_non_fossil['amount'] = 0.75152
Carbon_dioxide_non_fossil.save()
```