# When using Brightway, should I delete exchanges linked to an activity that I have erased?

Tags: brightway

This question is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033781/create-a-new-activity-in-brightway2-based-on-an-existing-ecoinvent-activity/43042637?noredirect=1#comment73979692_43042637) I raised about creating activities with Brightway 2 from a proxy activity. The question is: should I modify the table of exchanges if I decide to erase my proxy activity?

let's say I decide to create a heat pump in Quebec using as proxy a heat pump from Switzerland but adapting the origin of electricity.

```
#identify the activity supplying electricity from Quebec
for ds in Database('ei_33cutoff'):
   if ('market for electricity, low voltage' in ds['name']) &   (ds['location']=='CA-QC'):
       print(ds['name'])
       print(ds['code'])

elw_qc=Database('ei_33cutoff').get('44389eae7d62fa9d4ea9ea2b9fc2f609')

#identify the proxy activity
for ds in Database('ei_33cutoff'):
    if ('heat production, air-water' in ds['name']) & (ds['location']=='CH'):
       print(ds['name'],ds['location'],ds['code'])

hp_proxy=Database('ei_33cutoff').get('694d03f60920c0f7d964c08db1c67226')

#create a copy of the proxy
hp_qc=hp_proxy.copy()

#update location
hp_qc['location']='CA-QC'

#update electricity exchange
elect_to_hp = [exc for exc in hp_qc.technosphere() if 'electricity, low voltage' in exc['name']][0]
elect_to_hp['input']=elw_qc
elect_to_hp.save()

#store my new activity in the database

hp_qc.save()
```

However, if during this procedure I create a proxy activity that contains mistakes or for other reasons I no longer want. How should I "clean" the database from this activities containing mistakes? would hp_qc.delete() suffice? activities and exchanges [are stored in different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733371/brightway2-modifying-deleting-exchanges-from-activity-without-using-activity-as?noredirect=1&lq=1) in the SQLite database. I am wondering if I am "polluting" the exchange table with exchanges that are linked to activities that no longer exist, which could bring problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Activity.delete()` will [delete all exchanges](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/4ef52f9bfb169f4625e838d1461e4ff89be710d5/bw2data/backends/peewee/proxies.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#proxies.py-114) where your activity is the consumer, i.e. all incoming exchanges. It won't delete exchanges where other activities consumer your reference product, but as far as I can tell you don't have any exchange like that in this example.

There are a number of ways to "clean" the database, although such cleaning isn't really necessary in this case. The easiest is probably to learn how to use the [Exchanges object](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/4ef52f9bfb169f4625e838d1461e4ff89be710d5/bw2data/backends/peewee/proxies.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#proxies.py-21), then you can delete whatever you want.