# find a product that causes a non-square technosphere matrix with Brightway2

Tags: brightway

As a prophecy, I have a question related to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477048/when-using-brightway-should-i-delete-exchanges-linked-to-an-activity-that-i-hav) of "cleaning" the database. How can I identify why my technosphere is not longer square?

I have done something to my database that if I try to do an LCIA of a random activity

```
def testactivity(activity):
    method_key=methods.random()
    fu={activity:1}
    lca = LCA(fu,method_key)
    lca.lci()
    lca.lcia()
    print(lca.score)
    return()

    testactivity(Database('ei_33consequential').random())
```

I get this warning message: NonsquareTechnosphere: Technosphere matrix is not square: 12384 activities (columns) and 12385 products (rows). Use LeastSquaresLCA to solve this system, or fix the input data.

I tried to find if I have a dataset with two reference products, to check that I looped through the database to check if the "production amount" was not a float. but I didn't find anything "wrong"

```
for ds in Database('ei_33consequential'):
    if (isinstance(act['production amount'],float))==False:
        print(ds['name'])
```

Is this approach correct to find an activity with more than one reference flow?. Otherwise, how can I find the product which is making my matrix non inversable?

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see which activities have more than one production exchange with something like this:

```
for a in Database("ecoinvent 3.3 cutoff"):
    assert len(a.production()) == 1
```

Comment: Thanks!, although I did not find any activity with more than one reference product. Is there a way to check if a production exchange in the database is not produced by any activity?